# How to quickly install single or multiple R packages on an HPC system without encountering errors?

Tags: r, geospatial, centos7, hpc, terra

I want to run an analysis on netcdf using shapefiles in R on my institute HPC system but unable to install required packages as it shows error messages which I am unable to resolve. I wanted to understand how installing and loading R packages (along with any dependencies) work in HPC environment.

Error message I got while installing geodata and terra packages on HPC -

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPWoK.png)

I loaded modules R/4.2.1, gnu8/8.3.0,  mvapich2/2.3.2, openmpi/4.1.3, spack/0.17

$R

\>install.packages("terra")

Selected CRAN mirror from the list. But installation was not successful.

Comment: Is gdal available on your HPC system? The error indicates that gdal-config is missing.

Comment: Please [do not post code or error in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). It makes it more difficult for people to search for similar errors in the future. Note that some packages have "SystemRequirements" listed on CRAN which the package itself cannot install. Those must be installed on the system before the package can be installed.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick , I will try this out. I will take care to post code as text in my questions in future.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).